# Como hacer para que mi taximetro continue corriendo aun cuando el movil este con la pantalla apagada?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

buen día, hice un taximetro (es un cronometro que aumenta sus minutos cada 24 segundos). Funciona muy bien. Sin embargo cuando apago la pantalla del movil o la bloqueo, el taximetro se detiene y cuando vuelvo a encender o desbloquear la pantalla, el taximetro continua corriendo pero desde el ultimo minuto que quedo antes de apagar la pantalla. Lo que quiero lograr es que el taximetro continue corriendo con normalidad, así la pantalla del movil este apagada o bloqueada.
El proyecto esta escrito en angular. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.
[image: con la funcion iniciarViaje() se inicia el taximetro, la funcion taximetro tiene el funcionamiento principal]

Comment: Hola Deivid, bienvenido. Te recomiendo adjuntes el fragmento de codigo que estes utilizando para cargar actualmente el taximetro.

Comment: Buenas, además del código te consulto: Lo hiciste como un servicio? en el caso de aplicaciones angular, van a depender de la ejecución del javascript, y si mal no recuerdo, para que puedas ejecutarlo así, tendría que ser una pwa.

Comment: si exacto, es una PWA. sin embargo cuando la pantalla del celular se apaga o se bloquea el taximetro se detiene. ya adjunto el codigo

Comment: ya subi una imagen para que lo puedan ver, muchas gracias.

Comment: Algo como que se siga ejecutando en segundo plano, mientras el usuario hace otras cosas en su movil. gracias

Comment: En lugar de ir incrementando unidades yo te recomendaria que tomaras nota del timestamp cuando inicias el taximetro, y luego cuando refresques la pantalla hagas el calculo del tiempo que ha pasado desde esa fecha. la funcion `Date.now()` o la libreria `moment` deberian ayudarte a capturar el timestamp

Comment: vale, voy a intentarlo, si me sale de esa manera y te cuento. gracias